# Problem while creation of Directory on Server

Tags: php

I am working on a website where i am in need of creation of a directory but i am receiving an error

> Warning: mkdir(hello) [function.mkdir]: Permission denied in       E:\inetpub\vhosts\www.example.com\createaccount.php on line 33

I am using simple mkdir function, that works fine on localhost. If anybody can help me regarding to this problem. Thanks.

Comment: "Permission denied" usually means that you don't have the necessary rights to create the directory

Comment: I know but please guide me how i can create on my server.

Comment: @Rana your server administrator should be able to sort this out

Comment: You're probably using Unix-based OS, so... read about [CHMOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod). It is a basic permission mechanism and as a PHP programmer you **have to** understand how it's works.

Comment: I have used chmod but it didn't work

Comment: chmod('/Users', 0777); 
mkdir("Users/hello",0700);

Answer (score 0):

You don't have permissions to make a directory there.

Comment: @Pekka Oh yep, missed that :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assure that you have the required permissions to make it so. Use a service account that your website will use to write this directory to the drive or grant the permissions that will allow you to write to the drive at the specified location.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that PHP CLI and Apache usually are running as different users. If you created some directories from the PHP command line and now want to access the same directory from the Apache context, it will not work. Sidenote: it is probably not advantagous to create directories on the fly during a web request, please pay attention to the 30 sec. limit.